# Executing `gradle signingReport` doesn't show anything

Tags: android, flutter, dart, gradle

I'm trying to get my SHA-1 key by typing `gradle signingReport` and hitting Ctrl + Enter in the Terminal, but all it does is open the Run tab and show this:

```
5:10:36 PM: Executing 'signingReport'...

5:10:36 PM: Execution finished 'signingReport'.
```

This is for a Flutter app. I'm trying to test out an [open-source project I found on Github](https://github.com/CharlyKeleb/SocialMedia-App).

Comment: It might help to link the project, it might have custom signing configs which is causing it not to work.

Comment: @Philio I added the link